# Java - JSONObject Not Found

Tags: java, json

I am trying to collect a single piece of data from an API, that being the population of a certain country. Everything works properly except for cutting the population value out of the JSON.

```
{"Info":[{"area":301336,"nativeName":"Italia","capital":"Rome","demonym":"Italian","flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/ita.svg","alpha2Code":"IT","languages":[{"nativeName":"Italiano","iso639_2":"ita","name":"Italian","iso639_1":"it"}],"borders":["AUT","FRA","SMR","SVN","CHE","VAT"],"subregion":"Southern Europe","callingCodes":["39"],"regionalBlocs":[{"otherNames":[],"acronym":"EU","name":"European Union","otherAcronyms":[]}],"gini":36,"population":60665551,"numericCode":"380","alpha3Code":"ITA","topLevelDomain":[".it"],"timezones":["UTC+01:00"],"cioc":"ITA","translations":{"br":"Itália","de":"Italien","pt":"Itália","ja":"イタリア","hr":"Italija","it":"Italia","fa":"ایتالیا","fr":"Italie","es":"Italia","nl":"Italië"},"name":"Italy","altSpellings":["IT","Italian Republic","Repubblica italiana"],"region":"Europe","latlng":[42.83333333,12.83333333],"currencies":[{"symbol":"\u20ac","code":"EUR","name":"Euro"}]}]}
```

Within the JSON, It is called "Population".

This is my user input code

```
public static String UserInputsDetails() {
    System.out.println("Please input the country name");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Input = in.nextLine();
    return Input;
}
```

This is my JSON Getter Code

```
    public static JSONArray MakeConnection(String countryname) {
    JSONArray JSON = null;
    try {

        String url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/" + countryname;

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        JSON = new JSONArray(response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return JSON;
}
```

This is my Result code, to get just the population

```
    public static void PrintResult(JSONArray JSON){
    String population = null;
try {
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
    jobj.put("Info", JSON);

    population = jobj.getString("population");
    System.out.println(jobj);

    System.out.println(population);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

And finally, this is my main

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    String Input =  UserInput.UserInputsDetails();
    JSONArray JSON = Connection.MakeConnection(Input);
    Result.PrintResult(JSON);
}
```

I get the error

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["population"] not found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and keep the code where you are calling `PrintResult` method.

Comment: "population" is not a JSONObject, it's an integer. You should do something like this: String population = jobj.getJSONObject(0).getString("population");

Comment: I've edited my answer, sorry

Comment: Typing String population = jobj.getString("population"); still yields the same result sadly.

Comment: Try typing: String population = jobj.getJSONObject(0).getString("population");

Comment: That gives me the error "The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Comment: Then try: String population = JSON.getJSONObject(0).getString("population"); Delete this part: JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
    jobj.put("Info", JSON); System.out.println(jobj); JSON is already an array, why are you converting it into a JSONObject?

Comment: Now it gives me a "JSONObject["population"] not a string.". Sorry for the trouble, I've updated my question with all of my code, maybe it helps in some way to understand the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this part:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
jobj.put("Info", JSON);

population = jobj.getString("population");
System.out.println(jobj);

System.out.println(population);
```

JSON is already an array, why are you converting it into a JSONObject?

Change to something like this:

```
Long population = JSON.getJSONObject(0).getLong("population");
```

Comment: It works now, thank you so much and sorry for any hassle!